# How to intercept a right-click on a cell in spreadJS

Tags: javascript, event-handling, spreadjs

I'm trying to intercept a right-click event with spreadJS, sadly the event doesn't exist on the list : [SpreadJS Events Type](https://help.grapecity.com/spread/SpreadSheets12/webframe.html#SpreadJS%7EGC.Spread.Sheets.Events.html), only left click can be intercepted.

Is there any way to intercept a right-click on a cell?

I know we can customize the context menu but I need to intercept the right-click because in my case I have disabled the context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is able to be accomplished by adding an event listener like so:

```
spread.options.allowContextMenu = false;
spread.getHost().addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
    // your code;
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This lead me to another question, on can I know the cell (row and column) on which I have done a right-click?

Comment: I was abale to find a solution thanks to the https://www.grapecity.com/forums/spread-sheets/conditionally-displaying-d comment. You must downlaod the zip example to get the `getCumulativeOffset`function and then with the `spread.hitTest`
, you can know in which cell you actually are. Tricky but it work at the end.